# How to present a Barchart and a Table in a single figure

Tags: list-manipulation, legending, charts

Using the following code,

```
air = {3, 1, 6};
water = {2, 4, 3};
road = {1, 0, 7};
root = {6, 1, 2};
clist = {"Belarus", "Georgia", "Armenia"};
BarChart[
 Transpose@{air, water},
 ChartLabels -> {clist, None},
 ChartLegends -> {"change in air", "flowing water"},
 ChartStyle -> {None, "Pastel"},
 FrameLabel -> {"", "Percent Change"},
 PlotTheme -> "Business"
        ]
```

I produce:

[image]

I also produce a Table of data associated with the `BarChart` by:

```
tab = TableForm[{air, water, road, root}, 
  TableHeadings -> {{"change in air", "flowing water", 
     "construction road", "agriculture root"}, None}]
```

I like to combine these two pieces of outputs (`Barchart` and `Table`) in the format given below:

[image]

I had difficulty joining the two pieces in such a way as to align the data columns with the associated country bars and moving the `ChartLabels` into the table in the same way as shown above. Using tones of the gray color in Table and Background is very useful to have a user-friendly look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

air = {3, 1, 6};
water = {2, 4, 3};
road = {1, 0, 7};
root = {6, 1, 2};
clist = {"Belarus", "Georgia", "Armenia"};

legends = Row /@
   Transpose[{{" ", " ", " ", " "},
     ColorData["Pastel"] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/3],
     {" change in air", " flowing water",
      " construction road", " agriculture root"}}];

bc = BarChart[
   Transpose@{air, water, road, root}, ChartLabels -> {clist, None},
   ChartStyle -> {None, "Pastel"},
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   AspectRatio -> 1.2];
```

Display

```
Column[{
  Grid[{{Rotate[
      Style["Percent Change", 10], Pi/2], bc}},
   ItemSize -> {{10, 14}, 7},
   Alignment -> Right],
  Grid[
   (Flatten /@
     Transpose[
      {legends, {air, water, road, root}}]),
   Dividers -> {False, Darker@Red},
   Alignment -> {{Left, Center}},
   Background ->
    {{Lighter[Gray, 0.8], {Lighter[Gray, 0.9]}}, 
     None},
   ItemSize -> {{12, 4, 4, 4}, Automatic}]},
 Spacings -> 0,
 Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.9]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** This is a rough cut at adjusting to a variable number of countries. It should give you something to experiment with and improve upon.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

air = {3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6};
water = {2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3};
road = {1, 0, 7, 1, 0, 7};
root = {6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2};
clist = {"Belarus", "Georgia", "Armenia",
   "CountryA", "CountryB", "CountryC"};

legends = Row /@
   Transpose[{
     {" ", " ", " ", " "},
     ColorData["Pastel"] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/3],
     {" ", " ", " ", " "},
     {"change in air", "flowing water",
      "construction road", "agriculture root"}}];

Manipulate[
 bc = BarChart[
   Transpose[#[[;; nbr]] & /@ {air, water, road, root}],
   ChartLabels -> {clist[[;; nbr]], None},
   ChartStyle -> {None, "Pastel"},
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   AspectRatio -> 1.2,
   ImageSize -> 60 nbr];
 Column[{Grid[{{Rotate[Style["Percent Change", 10], Pi/2], bc}}, 
    ItemSize -> {{10, 2 + 4 nbr}, (2 + 4 nbr)/1}, Alignment -> Right], 
   Grid[(Flatten /@ 
      Transpose[{legends, #[[;; nbr]] & /@ {air, water, road, root}}]), 
    Dividers -> {False, Darker@Red}, Alignment -> {{Left, Center}}, 
    Background -> {{Lighter[Gray, 0.8], {Lighter[Gray, 0.9]}}, None}, 
    ItemSize -> {Flatten[{12, ConstantArray[4, nbr]}], Automatic}]}, 
  Spacings -> 0, Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.9]],
 {{nbr, 3, "number of countries"}, Range[2, Length@clist]},
 Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a very nice picture. I appreciated both answers. There is a tiny issue with the linkage between the table and bar chart. In my replication, I noticed that columns of data in the table slightly move to the right when new data columns are added. Eventually, for a larger table, the data columns do not stay underneath the bar chart's country names. Is there a way to link the total length of all the bars for a country to the associated data column centered at the total length? This way, adding new data columns will be always aligned to country groups.

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant "width", not "length" of the bars. The width of the table columns should be linked to the width of all the bars for a given country. Sorry for this confusion.

Comment: What have you tried and what haven't you been able to resolve? What is the maximum number of countries that would be used? Do all of the countries need to be displayed at once, or could a dynamic view of a subset of them be used? If a dynamic view, can the subset be determined by just sliding through the list or do you need to pick an arbitrary subset of at most `n` of them. The length of the country names could become an issue, what is the longest name that is to be used?

Comment: I added a fourth country `Timor-Leste` and saw that the bar chart is smaller than the table. Proportionality is destroyed. I can use the UN country codes such as `USA`, `GBR`, `TUR` etc to get around this name problem. I have a list of 230 countries, and I will be choosing `at most` 20-25 countries at a time. The numbers in the table are of the form `2.5743` maximum. Since I use `Dataset[]`, having a `Manipulate` code will be more convenient for quick selection of country and data.

Comment: An arbitrary subset of at most `n=25`. I always use a subset of 230 countries.

Comment: You haven't addressed the most important question relative to the issues you raise "What have you tried and what haven't you been able to resolve?" Just saying you added more data doesn't reflect any effort. In any event, this goes way beyond the scope of the OP and should be put in a new question to include what you have tried to resolve the issues.

Comment: I tried to change the parameters in your code to correctly add a new country to the bar chart. The window for the bar chart is too tiny to even enlarge manually it to get the same length as the table. If you think that this small addition deserves to be formulated as a new question, I can do that. I do not request `Manipulate` or other dynamic extensions, which demand a new question. I just wanted to know how to manually adjust the window of the bar chart. That will solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit. I will experiment with it. Regards.

Answer (score 6):

A custom `DisplayFunction` that adds legends and data table with columns aligned with group labels:

```
ClearAll[displayF]

displayF[lgnds_, tbl_, lbgrnd_: Automatic, tbgrnd_: Automatic, voffset_: 25, gap_:25] :=
 Module[{volist = Accumulate[Prepend[gap] @ ConstantArray[voffset, Length @ tbl]],
    hoffset = 1.1 Max[Ceiling[Rasterize[Style[#, "Graphics"], 
       "RasterSize"], 10][[1]] & /@ lgnds],
    hcoords = Map[MinMax @* Flatten] @
     Partition[Cases[#[[1]], (RectangleBox | Rectangle)[a_, b_, ___] :> 
       {First @ a, First @ b}, All], Length[tbl]],
    legendalign = ("MarkerLayout" /. Options[First@lgnds]) /. {"After" -> 1, _ -> -1},
    hrange, offsets, texts, tablelegend, ma},
   hrange = MinMax @ hcoords;
   ma = MovingAverage[volist, 2];
   offsets = Outer[Offset, Thread[{0, -ma}], Thread[{Mean /@ hcoords, 0}], 1];
   texts = Join @@ MapThread[Text[##, {0, 0}] &, {tbl, offsets}, 2];
   tablelegend = {lbgrnd /. Automatic -> Lighter[Gray, .5], 
     Rectangle @@ MapThread[Offset[{-#, -#2}, {hrange[[1]], 0}] &, 
        {{hoffset, 0}, volist[[{1, -1}]]}],
     tbgrnd /. Automatic -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
     Rectangle @@ MapThread[Offset[{0, -#}, {#2, 0}] &, {volist[[{1, -1}]], hrange}],
     CapForm["Round"], Thick, Darker @ Red,  
     Table[Line[{Offset[{-hoffset, -i}, {hrange[[1]], 0}], 
          Offset[{0, -i}, {hrange[[2]], 0}]}], {i, volist}],
     Black, texts,
     MapThread[Inset[#, Offset[{- hoffset Boole[legendalign < 0], -#2}, 
         {hrange[[1]], 0}], {legendalign, Center}] &, {lgnds, ma}]};
   Show[#, Graphics @ tablelegend, PlotRange -> All]] &
```

***Examples:***

```
air = {3, 1, 6}; water = {2, 4, 3}; road = {1, 0, 7}; root = {6, 1, 2};
data = {air, water, road, root};

clist = {"Belarus", "Georgia", "Armenia"};

legendlabels = {"change in air", "flowing water", "construction road",
    "agriculture root"};

colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale@Range[Length @ data];

legends = MapThread[
    SwatchLegend[{#}, {#2}, LegendLayout -> "Column", "MarkerLayout" -> "After"] &, 
   {colors, StringPadLeft[legendlabels]}];

BarChart[Transpose @ data,
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[clist, Below], None},
 ChartStyle -> {None, "Rainbow"},
 FrameLabel -> {{"PercentChange", None}, {None, None}},
 PlotTheme -> "Business",
 AspectRatio -> 2/3,
 ImageSize -> 600, 
 DisplayFunction -> displayF[legends, data]]
```

[image]

Let

```
legends2 = MapThread[SwatchLegend[{#}, {#2}, LegendLayout -> "Column"] &, 
   {colors, legendlabels}];
```

and use `DisplayFunction -> displayF[legends2, data]` to get:

[image]

Use

```
DisplayFunction -> 
  displayF[Append[{LegendMarkerSize -> 20, LegendMarkers -> "Bubble", 
     LabelStyle -> {White, 24}}] /@ legends, 
   Map[Map[Style[#, 24, White] &]] @ data, Black, Gray, 40]
```

to get

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
randomdata = RandomInteger[100, {5, 6}];

labels = RandomWord["Noun", 6];

legendLabels = Style[#, 14] & /@ Table[StringRiffle[RandomWord["Noun", 3]], 5];

swatchlegends = MapThread[
   SwatchLegend[{#}, {#2}, LegendLayout -> "Column", "MarkerLayout" -> "After"] &, 
   {ColorData["Pastel"] /@ Rescale[Range @ 5], legendLabels}];

BarChart[Transpose @ randomdata, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[labels, Below], None}, 
 ChartStyle -> {None, "Pastel"},
 FrameLabel -> {{"PercentChange", None}, {None, None}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", AspectRatio -> 2/3, ImageSize -> 800, 
 DisplayFunction -> displayF[swatchlegends, 
   Map[Style[#, 14, White] &] /@ randomdata, Automatic, Black]]
```

[image]

```
twogroups = randomdata[[All, ;; 2]];

twolabels = labels[[;; 2]];

BarChart[Transpose @ twogroups , 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[twolabels, Below], None}, 
 ChartStyle -> {None, "Pastel"},
 BarSpacing -> {.25, 2}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"PercentChange", None}, {None, None}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", AspectRatio -> 2/3, ImageSize -> 800, 
 DisplayFunction -> displayF[swatchlegends, 
   Map[Style[#, 14, White] &] /@ twogroups, Automatic, Black]]
```

[image]

Comment: A perfect figure!!! Much much more beautiful than the original figure I posted.

Comment: Editions are very useful indeed. I tried to use them but somehow they did not work. I wonder whether you revised the `displayF` function.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, i made many revisions  in the definition of `displayF` (you can see all the edits in [revisions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/261296/revisions)). The latest version works both in version 11.3.0 and version 13.0.

Comment: I copied the entire code in a new notebook and run it. Still, the newly added `legends2` and `DisplayFunction->...` with `Bubble` are not working but the rest is working just fine. I do not receive any error but the `displayF` is printed with no error message.

Comment: @TugrulTemel,   by  _"use `DisplayFunction -> displayF[legends2, data]`"_ I meant  replace `DisplayFunction -> displayF[legends, data]` above with `DisplayFunction -> displayF[legends2, data]`.

Comment: I revised `BarChart` with the revisions concerned. Now it works like in your answer. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
air = {3, 1, 6};
water = {2, 4, 3};
road = {1, 0, 7};
root = {6, 1, 2};
fig = BarChart[Transpose@{air, water}, ChartStyle -> {None, "Pastel"},
    FrameLabel -> {None, 
     Style["Percent Change", 13, Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Business", ImageSize -> 240, 
   ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 1}, {5, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1.5];
tab = TableForm[{air, water, road, root}, 
   TableHeadings -> {{Row[{RGBColor[
        0.7817626205714286, 0.5184517919999999, 0.9458540697142858], 
        Style["change in air", 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}, 
       Spacer[0.2]], 
      Row[{RGBColor[
        0.45017355885714305`, 0.7203669629714287, 0.9303642073142858],
         Style["flowing water", 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}, 
       Spacer[0.2]], 
      Style["construction road", 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
      Style["agriculture root", 13, 
       FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}, {Style["Belarus", 13, 
       FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
      Style["Georgia", 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
      Style["Armenia", 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}}, 
   TableAlignments -> Center];
Overlay[{Graphics[{FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.9]], Rectangle[]}, 
   ImageSize -> 440], 
  Multicolumn[{fig, tab}, 1, Spacings -> 0, Alignment -> Right]}, 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

Here is a quick and dirty way to do it. This can be improved further.

```
air = {3, 1, 6};
water = {2, 4, 3};
road = {1, 0, 7};
root = {6, 1, 2};
clist = {"Belarus", "Georgia", "Armenia"};
fig = BarChart[Transpose@{air, water}, ChartLabels -> {clist, None}, 
   ChartStyle -> {None, "Pastel"}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"", "Percent Change"}, PlotTheme -> "Business"];

tab = TableForm[{air, water, road, root}, 
   TableHeadings -> {{Row[{RGBColor[
        0.7817626205714286, 0.5184517919999999, 0.9458540697142858], 
        "change in air"}, Spacer[0.2]], 
      Row[{RGBColor[
        0.45017355885714305`, 0.7203669629714287, 0.9303642073142858],
         "flowing water"}, Spacer[0.2]], "construction road", 
      "agriculture root"}, None}];

Overlay[{Graphics[{FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.9]], Rectangle[]}, 
   ImageSize -> 250], Multicolumn[{fig, tab}, 1, Alignment -> Right]},
  Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]