# How to create a flexible BarChart[ ] with Manipulate[ ]

Tags: legending, code-request, charts, code-review

This question is nothing more than making a few changes to an already working [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261296/60365). I put that code into `Manipulate[...]` to be able to choose a subset of countries and a subset of indicators.

By @kglr, the code below creates a perfect chart:

```
ClearAll[displayF]

displayF[lgnds_, tbl_, lbgrnd_: Automatic, tbgrnd_: Automatic, voffset_: 25, gap_:25] :=
 Module[{volist = Accumulate[Prepend[gap] @ ConstantArray[voffset, Length @ tbl]],
    hoffset = 1.1 Max[Ceiling[Rasterize[Style[#, "Graphics"], 
       "RasterSize"], 10][[1]] & /@ lgnds],
    hcoords = Map[MinMax @* Flatten] @
     Partition[Cases[#[[1]], (RectangleBox | Rectangle)[a_, b_, ___] :> 
       {First @ a, First @ b}, All], Length[tbl]],
    legendalign = ("MarkerLayout" /. Options[First@lgnds]) /. {"After" -> 1, _ -> -1},
    hrange, offsets, texts, tablelegend, ma},
   hrange = MinMax @ hcoords;
   ma = MovingAverage[volist, 2];
   offsets = Outer[Offset, Thread[{0, -ma}], Thread[{Mean /@ hcoords, 0}], 1];
   texts = Join @@ MapThread[Text[##, {0, 0}] &, {tbl, offsets}, 2];
   tablelegend = {lbgrnd /. Automatic -> Lighter[Gray, .5], 
     Rectangle @@ MapThread[Offset[{-#, -#2}, {hrange[[1]], 0}] &, 
        {{hoffset, 0}, volist[[{1, -1}]]}],
     tbgrnd /. Automatic -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
     Rectangle @@ MapThread[Offset[{0, -#}, {#2, 0}] &, {volist[[{1, -1}]], hrange}],
     CapForm["Round"], Thick, Darker @ Red,  
     Table[Line[{Offset[{-hoffset, -i}, {hrange[[1]], 0}], 
          Offset[{0, -i}, {hrange[[2]], 0}]}], {i, volist}],
     Black, texts,
     MapThread[Inset[#, Offset[{- hoffset Boole[legendalign < 0], -#2}, 
         {hrange[[1]], 0}], {legendalign, Center}] &, {lgnds, ma}]};
   Show[#, Graphics @ tablelegend, PlotRange -> All]] &
```

And then, I adjusted @kglr's code using `Manipulate[ ]`

```
ClearAll[air, water, road, root, data, clist, xlist, colors, legends];

air = {3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6};
water = {2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3};
road = {1, 0, 7, 1, 0, 7};
root = {6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2};

data = {air, water, road, root};
clist = {"Belarus", "USA", "France", "Turkey", "Georgia", "China"};
xlist = {"change in air", "flowing water", "construction road", 
   "agriculture root"};

colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale@Range[Length@data];
legends = 
  MapThread[
   SwatchLegend[{#}, {#2}, LegendLayout -> "Column", 
     "MarkerLayout" -> "After"] &, {colors, StringPadLeft[xlist]}];

Manipulate[
 data1 = (#[[;; noC]] & /@ data);
 BarChart[
  Transpose@data1,
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[clist, Below], None},
  ChartStyle -> {None, "Rainbow"},
  FrameLabel -> {{"Percent Change", None}, {None, None}},
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
  AspectRatio -> 2/3,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  DisplayFunction -> displayF[legends, data1]
  ],
 {{noC, 4, "countries"}, Thread[Range[Length[clist]] -> clist], 
  ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{noV, 2, "indicators"}, Thread[Range[Length[xlist]] -> xlist], 
  ControlType -> SetterBar},
 Paneled -> False
 ]
```

This produced:

[image]

But there are two issues to solve:

1. When I choose a single country, such as `Turkey`, the code gives me all the countries listed before Turkey (including Turkey as well). I like to choose a few countries from the list `clist`;
2. I also like to choose at will a few indicators from the list `xlist`.

I tried the following:

```
Manipulate[
 data1 = {(#[[;; nbrC]] & /@ data)[[nbrV, All]]};
 BarChart[
  Transpose@data1,
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[clist, Below], None},
  ChartStyle -> {None, "Rainbow"},
  FrameLabel -> {{"Percent Change", None}, {None, None}},
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
  AspectRatio -> 2/3,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  DisplayFunction -> displayF[legends, data1]
  ],
 {{nbrC, 4, "countries"}, Thread[Range[Length[clist]] -> clist], 
  ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{nbrV, 2, "indicators"}, Thread[Range[Length[xlist]] -> xlist], 
  ControlType -> SetterBar},
 Paneled -> False
 ]
```

[image]

This trial is way behind what I hoped to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[With[{data1 = data[[noV, noC]]},
  If[noV == {} || noC == {}, 
   Graphics[{}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> 2/3, ImageSize -> 500], 
   BarChart[Transpose @ data1, 
    ChartLabels -> {Placed[clist[[noC]], Below], None}, 
    ChartStyle -> {None, colors[[noV]]}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"Percent Change", None}, {None, None}}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Business", AspectRatio -> 2/3, ImageSize -> 500, 
    DisplayFunction -> displayF[legends[[noV]], data1]]]], 
 {{noC, Range[Length[clist]], "countries"}, 
  Thread[Range[Length[clist]] -> clist], TogglerBar, 
  TrackingFunction -> (noC = Sort[#]; &)},
 {{noV, Range[Length[xlist]], "indicators"}, 
  Thread[Range[Length[xlist]] -> xlist], TogglerBar, 
  TrackingFunction -> (noV = Sort[#]; &)}, Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

A variation: replace the second control with

```
{{noV, Range[Length[xlist]], "indicators"}, 
 Thread[Range[Length[xlist]] -> (Append[#, 
       Background -> Opacity[.3, #[[1, 1]]]] & /@ legends)], 
 TogglerBar, Appearance -> { "Pressed", "Normal"}, 
 TrackingFunction -> (noV = Sort[#]; &)}
```

to get

[image]